# * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.rinkeby.url - Expected a value of type string

Tags: hardhat

The code is:

```
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle')
require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env'})

const ALCHEMY_API_URL = process.env.ALCHEMY_API_URL
const RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY

module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.9',
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: ALCHEMY_API_URL,
      accounts: [RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
}
```

It shows following error while running - `npx hardhat verify --network rinkeby` in the terminal

```
 Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.rinkeby.url - Expected a value of type string.
  * Invalid account: #0 for network: rinkeby - Expected string, received undefined
```

Comment: Can you log what's the value of `ALCHEMY_API_URL` when running the config file?

Comment: show me your .env file. this happens when your  keys in .env file not math in config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't give path inside config(), hardhat smart enough to know the files
Change your line 2

```sh
require("dotenv").config()
```

Mine work after removing path..